# How can i extract one letter from one column from dataset?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

i'm trying to take the second letter from group columns.
i used data['Group'][1:2] but it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will create a new column with that letter

```
df['Letter'] = df["Group"].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

If you want a list and not a new column in the data frame:

```
letters = list(df["Group"].apply(lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: I think `df['Group'].apply(lambda x: x[1])` will do the trick too

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes and it's probably better, this is a bad habbit that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
second_letter = []
for letter in df['Group']:
    i = letter[1:2]
    second_letter.append(i)
second_letter
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code using **STR SLICE**:

```
df['Letter'] = df['Group'].str.slice(1,2)
```